# Redis - sentinels will not pick a new master

Tags: redis

I am trying to remove the current master by stopping the redis and sentinel service. Prior to this I have set the priority of the current master to 0 but this does not seem to have made any difference.

`slave-priority 0`

One other sentinel is set to priority 25 and the other 2 are set to default 100.

I expected stopping the current masters service would cause the new master to be picked but this does not occur, instead the failover continues to try and fail.

`+odown master mymaster 192.168.10.227 6380 #quorum 3/3 [4456] 26 Sep 07:11:35.019 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Tue Sep 26 07:17:34 2023 [4456] 26 Sep 07:17:34.597 # +new-epoch 250 [4456] 26 Sep 07:17:34.613 # +vote-for-leader 386414673616c6a6b644565dea1eb6186f74f532 250 [4456] 26 Sep 07:17:34.628 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Tue Sep 26 07:23:35 2023 [4456] 26 Sep 07:23:34.659 # +new-epoch 251 [4456] 26 Sep 07:23:34.675 # +vote-for-leader 11a13e83219f33d2250fd040008be7d1d771e68f 251 [4456] 26 Sep 07:23:34.691 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Tue Sep 26 07:29:35 2023 [4456] 26 Sep 07:29:35.144 # +new-epoch 252`

There are 3 sentinels in total after stopping the old Master redis service. As the documentation mentions there should always be an odd number of nodes.

Comment: What's the output of the `SENTINEL CKQUORUM <master name>` command? And also how many sentinels do you have?